# C Having Trouble with Pointer Incrementing (I think)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, compilation

Quite a simple error I guess but I get this error when trying to compile my C code:

```
error: expected identifier before '(' token
```

From this code where I am trying to set up structs for a hash table with linked lists for hash collisions:

```
typedef struct bN {
    MEntry nestedEntry;
    struct bN *next;
} bucketNode;

typedef struct bL {
    bucketNode *first;
    int bucketSize;
} bucket;

struct mlist {
    bucket *currentTable;
};
```

And this code where I actually initialise the linked list:

```
MList *ml_create(void){

    MList *temp;

    if (ml_verbose){
        fprintf(stderr, "mlist: creating mailing list\n");
    }
    if ((temp = (MList *)malloc(sizeof(MList))) != NULL){
        temp->currentTable = (bucket *)malloc(tableSize * sizeof(bucket));
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < tableSize; i++){
            temp->(currentTable+i)->first = NULL; /**ERROR HERE*/
            temp->(currentTable+i)->bucketSize = 0; /**ERROR HERE*/
        }
    }
    return temp;

}
```

Comment: at which line the error is reported?

Comment: Sorry, don't think my comments were very visible. In the second block of code about 3/4 of the way down in the for loop :)

Comment: Btw: In C just do not cast the result of `malloc()`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/694576

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your syntax is off. You mean:

```
temp->currentTable[i].first = NULL;
temp->currentTable[i].bucketSize = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
temp->(currentTable+i)->first = NULL;
```

to be

```
(temp->currentTable+i)->first = NULL;
```